# Apply comparison between Integral and Fractional

Tags: haskell

I want to check if an `Integral` is a square:

```
isSquare :: Integral n => n -> Bool
isSquare n = (>1) $ length (filter (\x -> n / x == x) numList)
    where numList = reverse [1..n]
```

Apart from whether or not iterating through a list is the right approach here, when I try to compile this function I get the error:

```
No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
```

My understanding of this is that since I am binding `n` to the `Integral` type, by dividing it I am breaking the function's rigid type construction.  How can I fix my function so that it compiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add `fromIntegral` to everything to get `Fractional`s:

```
filter (\x -> fromIntegral n / fromIntegral x == fromIntegral x) numList
```

Or just square the number instead:

```
filter (\x -> n == x ^ 2)
```

Also, your length check shouldn’t be `>1`. `==1` would make more sense, but you should use `null` to avoid having to try every number every time (besides using a faster algorithm in the first place).

```
isSquare :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isSquare n = not $ null $ filter (\x -> n == x ^ 2) numList
    where numList = [n,n-1..1]
```

Comment: wouldnt converting from `Integral` to `Num` defeat the point of rigid binding?

Comment: The second solution, `n == x^2`, is clearly preferrable. This is actually a case where Haskell's requirement of explicit type conversion is not just good safety- and inference-wise, but also points at a way the original code was really not very sensible written. (Obviously, this is not the only thing that's less than optimal in the entire approach!)

Comment: I would write `[n,n-1..1]` -- feels a bit cleaner.